# Facebook app that signs user up to website upon user allow access

Tags: facebook, registration, facebook-apps, socialengine

I am looking for a way to make a Facebook app that signs the user up to an external website when the user installs the app and accepts/allows the app to share user information. I have been looking for a while, but still not sure what the main steps would look like. The external website was built using SocialEngine.net.

Answer (score 0):

Then you want to use the registration plug in:

See https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/registration